# Select query to pull same record twice

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, default, record

I want to use a select query to pull the same record two times but with a different value the 2nd time for one of the fields.

So I have a select query that currently pulls data and displays the following for example:

```
ProductCode   Description   Price   Currency
123           Product1      200     CAD
```

Now I want to use the select query to pull the same record a second time but instead of having CAD I want to use USD, so it should display:

```
ProductCode   Description   Price   Currency
123           Product1      200     CAD
123           Product1      200     USD
```

The "CAD" is hard-coded for now in the select query, I hope this makes sense, eg. the select query right now is:

```
select productcode,description,price, 'CAD' as Currency from product_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about union?

```
SELECT ProductCode, Description, price_in_cad as Price, 'CAD' as Currency FROM product_table
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductCode, Description, price_in_usd as Price, 'USD' as Currency FROM product_table;
```

Or if you want to order it or filter than you can make subquery from it:

```
SELECT result.* FROM (
  SELECT ProductCode, Description, price_in_cad as Price, 'CAD' as Currency FROM product_table
UNION ALL
  SELECT ProductCode, Description, price_in_usd as Price, 'USD' as Currency FROM product_table
) result ORDER BY Price;
```

Comment: Oh my god, actually it was that easy, thanks for that, the UNION ALL worked!